# How to insert null in datetime type column in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table in which there are some datetime type columns. I use a stored procedure to insert values into the table. In the stored procedure I have variables that accept null for inserting into the table. My problem is when I try to insert a null value into my table's datetime column it throws error.
my code is as.

```
    System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime getDate;
//set DateTime null
getDate = SqlDateTime.Null;

if (InsertDate.Text == "")
{
cmd1.Parameters["@InsertDate"].Value = getDate;
}
else
{
cmd1.Parameters["@InsertDate"].Value = InsertDate.Text;
}
```

Comment: Which error is thrown? Does the column allow null values?

Answer (score 17):

```
cmd1.Parameters["@InsertDate"].Value = getDate ?? DBNull.Value;
```

The key being DBNull.Value. I imagine you have a nullable DateTime variable, i.e. `DateTime? someVariable`. You can test it for null and if it is use `DBNull.Value` (as shown above).

Answer (score 9):

```
if (//some condition)   
{
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofBirth", txtdob.text);
}
else 
{ 
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofBirth", DBNull.Value); 
}
```

Comment: Should add that `//some condition` is if `txtdob.Text`, or in the OP's case, `InsertDate.Text`, is null or not...  `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(InsertDate.Text))` fits the bill, in this example.

Answer (score 5):

To pass null value to db you can use DBNull.Value. Please try this

```
 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(InsertDate.Text))
  {
   cmd1.Parameters["@InsertDate"].Value =DBNull.Value;
  }
 else
  {
   cmd1.Parameters["@InsertDate"].Value = InsertDate.Text;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

try using this

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.Null
```

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain how the code solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, to be able to insert `null` into a database column, the column must accept `null`s. Open the table in the designer, and see if the relevant column is nullable or not. If it's not and you try to insert a null value, you'll get the error:

> > Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'InsertDate', table 'TableName'; column does not allow nulls.

That said, since you are using stored procedures to insert data, I would recommend using default values for the parameters on the procedure level, instead of burdening the aplication code. Than, you can just not set the parameter on the application side, and it would work correctly:

```sql
 create procedure InsertIntoTable
   -- ....other parameters here...
   @InsertDate datetime = null -- this means that if the value is not supplied, 
                               -- null is used by default
 as begin
   insert into TableName (InsertDate) values (@InsertDate)
 end
```

and on the C# side, just do:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(InsertDate.Text)) {
  // check to see if the entered text is actually a date
  DateTime insertDate = ... some parsing/verification code...;
  cmd1.Parameters["@InsertDate"].Value = insertDate;
}
```

Note that there is no `else` branch, so if the `InsertDate` is empty, the parameter is not sent at all.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, using Add rather than AddWithValue..

```
DB.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to supply `null` directly as a parameter value:

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(InsertDate.Text)) {
    cmd1.Parameters["@InsertDate"].Value = null;
} else {
    cmd1.Parameters["@InsertDate"].Value = InsertDate.Text;
}
```

Also switched to using `String.IsNullOrWhitespace()` to check for an empty string.

Comment: Using null directly can lead to problems as parameter may not be sent (depending on statement and/or commandType)...DbNull.Value pretty much works every time

Comment: @Linky Ahh. I've never personally had issue with it but that's interesting to know and keep in mind.

Comment: When using a Command with commandType == StoredProcedure and the commandText is just the StoredProcedure name, parameters are added to the executed text (check for example with Sql Server profiler). If you add a Parameter with value null, the parameter won't be part of the executed sql any more and if your stored procedure requires this parameter, execution will fail. SWeko's answer also mentions that. 
If you're building statements like "Insert into X (col) values (@col)" it doesn't make a difference as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

In the stored procedure do something like this:

```
insert into table(date)
values(case when @InsertDate ='' then 
               null 
            else 
               @insertDate 
       end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(InsertDate.Text))
{
    cmd1.Parameters["@InsertDate"].Value = getDate;
}
else
{
    cmd1.Parameters["@InsertDate"].Value = InsertDate.Text;
}
```

Comment: This is basically what he was using, and what was throwing the error.  Issue is because it is sending `SqlDateTime.Null`, both on his and yours, when he should be sending `DBNull.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic if DBNull.Value is not worked .. use DateTime? null

Ensure that ur database field should allow null

dtexpiry!=null? dtexpiry :(DateTime?) null

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. There i no shortcut!!

if (InsertDate.Text == "")
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", **DBNull.Value**);
 else
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", **Convert.ToDateTime(InsertDate.Text)**);