# Null date in MS Access form causes error in SQL Server when table is updated using ADO & VBA

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ms-access, stored-procedures, ado

My form in MS Access has 10 fields on it - three are date fields updated in sequence - ('Start Date', 'Expected End Date', 'Actual End Date'.) Actual End Date is always NULL the first time the form is updated and Expected End Date may be null on the first few edits too.

When I edit the form and click the update button, a VBA routine calls the SQL Server stored procedure to update the database with changes/new values.

All works good - except if I leave any date fields as NULL (which they have to be for the business process) I get an error when the VBA executes the stored procedure. Please see the code I have used to date (and I have spent many hours on this with no luck)

***Error Details:  3421
Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation.***

---

```
    Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()

    Dim Con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim rtn As Integer
    Dim dtStartDate As Date
    Dim dtProjectedEnd As Date
    Dim dtActualEnd As Date

    On Error GoTo HandleErr

   Set Con = New ADODB.Connection
   Con.ConnectionString = fnProvider
   Con.Open

   Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

   With cmd
      .ActiveConnection = Con
      .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

      Select Case frmStatus
         Case "Add"
           .CommandText = "dbo.spAddProjectPhaseDetail"
         Case "Edit"
           .CommandText = "dbo.spEditProjectPhaseDetail"
      End Select
 .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@PhaseDetailID", adinteger, adparaminput, , Me.txtPhaseDetailID)
 .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ProjPhaseID", adinteger, adparaminput, , Me.cboProjPhase)
 .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ProjectID", adVarChar, adparaminput, 10, Me.txtProjectID)
 .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@PhaseLead", adinteger, adparaminput, , Me.cboTestLead)
 If IsNull(Me.txtStartDt) Then
     MsgBox "You must include a phase start date - this can be an estimate", vbExclamation, "Input Error"
    GoTo ExitSub
 End If
 .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@PhaseStartDate", adDate, adparaminput, 9, Me.txtStartDt)
 .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@PhaseProjectedEndDate", adDBDate, adparaminput, 9, Nz(Me.txtProjectedEnd, Null))
 .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@PhaseActualEndDate", adDBDate, adparaminput, 9, Nz(Me.txtActualEnd, Null))
 .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@SoftwareBuild", adVarChar, adparaminput, 20, Nz(Me.txtSoftwareBuild, ""))
 .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@SysEnvironmentID", adVarChar, adparaminput, 50, Nz(Me.txtSysEnvironment, ""))
 .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@IsCurrent", adinteger, adparaminput, , Nz(Me.chkCurrent, 0))
 .Execute rtn
End With

If rtn = 0 Then
   Err.Raise 10005, , "Could not add record to database."
Else
   MsgBox IIf(frmStatus = "Edit", "Record Updated", "Record Added"), vbInformation, "Data Update"
End If

ExitSub:
 Con.Close
 Set Con = Nothing
 Set cmd = Nothing
 frmStatus = ""
 DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmAddProjectPhases"
 Exit Sub

 HandleErr:

 MsgBox "[" & Err.Number & "] " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "If the error persisits, please contact support."
  Call sbSysErrorLogUpdate(Err.Number, Err.Description, "Target:frmAddProjectProjectPhases/cmdUpdate_Click()")
  Err.Clear
  GoTo ExitSub
```

---

The Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spEditProjectPhaseDetail] 

@PhaseDetailID          Integer,
@ProjPhaseID            Integer,
@ProjectID              varchar(10),
@PhaseLead              integer, 
@PhaseStartDate         DATE,
@PhaseProjectedEndDate  date = NULL,
@PhaseActualEndDate     date = NULL,
@SoftwareBuild          varchar(50) = NULL,
@SysEnvironmentID       varchar(50) = NULL,
@IsCurrent              bit = 0

AS

BEGIN

   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   UPDATE dbo.tblProjPhaseDetail
   Set
     fPROJ_PHASE_ID = @ProjPhaseID,
     fPROJECT_ID = @ProjectID,
     fPHASE_LEAD = @PhaseLead,
     PHASE_START_DT = @PhaseStartDate,
     PHASE_PROJECTED_END_DT = @PhaseProjectedEndDate,
     PHASE_ACTUAL_END_DT = @PhaseActualEndDate,
     SOFTWARE_BUILD = @SoftwareBuild,
     SYS_ENVIRONMENT_ID = @SysEnvironmentID

    WHERE PHASE_DETAIL_ID = @PhaseDetailID
END
```

---

I'd be grateful for any getting this procedure to run with the Null dates. Thanks

Comment: Any help in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098659/how-to-insert-null-in-datetime-type-column-in-sql-server or https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/de253497-9795-4dfd-8985-83a2ec49f062/inserting-null-values-via-stored-procedures or https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/null-value-handling-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

Apologies - the answer is quite simple. I changed the parameter type from adDAte to adDBDate fro the parameters that need to pass null and it worked. Also there was a coding error - I had left the 'size' value in the parameters for the dates - in a previous attempt I had tried passing the dates as strings.-